# Displaying lines with diffent values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an ID and Value column. I need to display lines in which the value(in Value column) in curent line is different from the value in the previous line. Tried to use lag but it doesn't work as it should.

It should display 1,5,7,9.(example)

+----+-------+
| ID | Value |
+----+-------+
| 1  |  10   |
| 3  |  10   |
| 5  |  20   |
| 6  |  20   |
| 7  |  30   |
| 9  |  40   |
| 10 |  40   |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
select id, value
from (select t.*, lag(value) over (order by id) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t
where prev_value is null or prev_value <> value
order by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Андрей. Please, try this:

```
SELECT id,value FROM
(
 SELECT id, value, LAG(value)OVER (order by id) prevVal
 from tab
) X 
WHERE (prevVal<>value) or (prevVal IS NULL)
```